# Normilized correlation function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i am trying to write a normilized cross-correlation method function , but i can't complete it. Here are the details of the formula :
[image]

My code is:

```
x=rand(1,1000);
N=length(x); %// length of signal
n1=128;  %// length of window 
xf=framing(x,n1,n1/2,rectwin(n1)); %this function frames the signal i    will get xf(128,14)
win_num=size(xf,2);
for col=1:win_num
   for m=1:n1+1 
      for n=1:n1-m
        ccor(m,col)=sum(xf(n+m,col)*(xf(n,col)))/  sqrt(sum(xf(n)^2)*sum(xf(n+m)^2) );
      end
   end
end
```

Note that i want to see the correlation values betwen -1 and 1 like in the picture. So does anybody have any clue? or maybe i did something wrong in my code? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is that code not working?

Comment: Why not use [`xcorr(..., 'coeff')`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html)? That seems to do that you need

Comment: The code is working but i don't get the result i want, yes indeed i could use 'coeff '  but it  normalizes the sequence so that the autocorrelations at zero lag equal 1. Instead i want to be from -1 to 1.

Comment: "_I could use 'coeff ' but it normalizes the sequence so that the __auto__-correlations at zero lag equal 1. Instead I want to be from -1 to 1_". They are two ways of saying the same thing. Check the result of `xcorr([1 2 3],[-1 -2 -3],'coeff')`

Comment: ok i see the plot is from -1 that's fine, but i want it to be [-1 1] , so you say it's the same thing? if it is then it will do , thanks a lot anyway

Comment: The result will reach +1 / -1 or not, depending on your input vectors. But I think it `xcorr(..., ' coeff')` does what you want